# python-telegram-bot not respond after long time not use

Tags: python-telegram-bot

Usually my Bot work normal.
When long time not to use then use again,the first time execute command not respond.
And console debug no any logging.
After a moment, execute command then normal.

What root cause for this and how to solve?